# Magento Theme painfully slow

Tags: magento

We are currently developing a new Magento theme for our website www.sointeriors.co.uk and while we are developing we are using the domain name www.auctionbaby.co.uk

Now as you will see from looking at our current website it loads fairly quickly however the new theme takes over 20 seconds to load up and the developer has no explanation as to why this is happening.

The development website is a clone of the live site and is running on the same server so it's not a server issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is literally no possible way to provide a sound answer to this.  You need to internally debug and investigate the issue on your own server.  From an outside perspective it's difficult to tell what the bottleneck is, it looks like your server is stuggling with serving up the request.  Check logs, try removing theme files until the issue goes away, work backwards towards the default theme and remove 3rd party customization until the issue is fixed.  Basic debugging will help you narrow down what the issue actually is.

Comment: Profile your application to find the bottle necks.

Comment: Wow, that is slow. 60+ seconds. If it is simply a theme change and no additional modules are installed, and same server, then my best guess is the theme/templates are doing something different to your old site which is clearly more intensive than your old site. You need to debug the problem as it could be 1 of 1000 things, take a look at Zends Z-Ray (http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/z-ray-magento-demo) as it will show you all the blocks and SQL queries and execution time and assist with identifying where the bottleneck is. Are your cache settings also the same, are using APC etc.

Answer (score 0):

it's indeed very slow. There are a few things you can do:

- If you are using Chrome, open the inspector, switch to Network tab, tick the Preserve log and reload the site. (better to this on your local environment). This will give you a brief idea of what's involve.
- Install this module: http://fbrnc.net/blog/2012/08/magento-profiler#hello. This will give you a full information and most likely will show bottleneck(s).

On my Chrome inspector the waiting time of the main page take 3 minutes, most in the Waiting (TTFB). This show that there's something in the page rendering that taking up lots of resource. Could be products collections loading with many attributes (my guess). Try turning on Flat catalog and reindex the data, this may help a little. Best solution is to use the above module.

Comment: My guess is a poorly written SQL query, or an infinite loop somewhere in the theme.